# Как узнать параметры FastCGI?

Tags: php, apache, fastcgi

Иногда скрипт падает при дебаге, когда остановится на брейкпоинте по таймауту. Грешу на **FcgidIOTimeout**, так как по умолчанию у него 40 секунд и в логах `mod_fcgid: read data timeout in 40 seconds`.

Вопрос в следующем. Как узнать какие параметры сейчас использует FCGI?

Comment: Все параметры тут: `/etc/apache2/mods-available/fcgid.conf` (дебиан) или тут: `/etc/httpd/conf.d/fcgid.conf` (сентось). Посмотреть все таймауты: `grep -i timeout /etc/apache2/mods-available/fcgid.conf` (на дебиане)

Comment: А если в *fcgid.conf* никаких таймаутов нет.

Comment: Тогда варианты такие: либо инклудится еще один файл, либо используется значение по-умолчанию, либо передается из окружения. `.htaccess` есть секция `mod_fcgid.c`? Или если это шаред хостинг - нет ли там `php.ini` файла в корне проекта?

Comment: И чтобы сразу глянуть окружение: `top -b | grep 'php'` - выдаст таблицу запущенных процессов php. Первым будет идти pid процесса, это число. Берем pid процесса, затем `sudo cat /proc/7505/environ` (в примере 7505 - pid процесса), все что выдало - покажите! И до кучи `sudo cat /proc/7505/cmdline`

Comment: Удалось найти значение параметра?

Comment: нет( Всё что показывает, это то что я сам прописал в конфигах fcgi

Comment: `/proc/пид-fcgid/environ` и `cat /proc/пид-fcgid/cmdline` что выдает? Есть `.htaccess`? Что в `php.ini`?